# pouchdb doesn't sync all doc to couchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using `pouchdb` in a website and `couchdb` on the server side. I use below code in `pouchdb` to sync to `couchdb`:

```
db.replicate.to(remoteDb ...
```

for some reasons one of the documents is not synced to `couchdb` but all others sync successfully. I can see that the missing document exists on `pouchdb` but I can't fine it on `coudhdb`. I have tried multiple times on syncing but none of them working. The problem only happens on one of the document. How can I check the error about syncing this document? Where is the log about failed sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the functionality correctly, when replicating **from** the server, a **server side** filter must allow your data to pass. When replicating **to** the server, a **client side** filter must allow your data to pass.

In your case you need to test your assumption that the data can indeed pass your client side filter.

Let's say I have a filter like this...

```
{
  "_id": "_design/post_processing",
  "_rev": "1-47235d8ded76c0ec3c3c49e5aae71f6f",
  "filters": {
    "by_request": "function(doc, req) { doc.data && doc.data.type && doc.data.type == 'Request' }"
  }
}
```

My records are obviously going to pass because they have data type 'request', right?

To check that, I test my assumption directly in the code before starting the replicator.

```
const doc = {
  "_id": "Person_1_0000000000000339",
  "_rev": "2-86e5ce7d8b5b58dacd2fad68bcc02658",
  "data": {
    "pk": 339,
    "type": "request",
    "handler": "PersonUpdate"
    "mobile": "099-555-7685",
    "distributor": true,
    "email": "bill.gates@amazon.com",
  }
};

console.log('=========== HEY! Look here. Here I am! ================');
console.log(doc.data && doc.data.type && doc.data.type == 'Request');

db.replicate.to(remoteDb ...
```

Oh crap.  It's false. I wonder why.

Comment: I didn't set any filter on `pouchdb`. Is there any log I can view on either `pouchdb` or `couchdb` to check why this happens?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=couchdb+view+filter+log  &&  https://www.google.ca/search?q=pouchdb+debug+mode